# Python Pandas - groupby and get related column from aggregate

Tags: python, pandas

Fairly new to both Python and Pandas and looking for some help in grouping a dataframe.

What I'm tryin to do is filter the csv using Pandas groupby method on the Packages field maintaining only unique Package values, while keeping the Score field with the highest value for the Package, the Date field with the newest date for that Package, and the Street field that correlates to the Date field with the newest date (Street field is in the same row as the Date field)

The input is a csv file and the dataframe looks like this:

```
ID   Packages  Score  Street    Date
012  p1        8.1    Oak       2020-09-29 
022  p2        9.0    Green     2020-02-02
333  p2        7.6    Orchard   2021-12-20
333  p3        5.5    Main      2021-05-04
445  p3        7.8    West      2020-03-03
445  p3        6.0    North     2020-10-16
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is this:

```
ID   Packages  Score  Street    Date
012  p1        8.1    Oak       2020-09-29 
022  p2        9.0    Orchard   2021-12-20
445  p3        7.8    Main      2021-05-04
```

I'm using the following groupby:

```
df = df.groupby(['Packages']).agg({'Score':'max', 'Date':'max'})[['Score','Date']]

Output:
print(df)

Packages  Score   Date
p1        8.1     2020-09-29 
p2        9.0     2021-12-20
p3        7.8     2021-05-04
```

What I'm missing is adding the "Street" value that correlates with the Date column, and also adding in the ID column.

I'm hoping this makes sense and any help that points me in the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: You almost got it.  I'd create a new dataframe `dfA = df.groupby(...)` and then merge `df` into `dfA` like `dfA = dfA.merge(df, on = ['Packages','Score','Date'], how = 'left')`

Answer (score 0):

Sort the dataframe by "Date" and then aggregate on "Score", "Street" and "Date" (street and date should be "last"):

```
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
df = df.sort_values(by="Date")
print(
    df.groupby("Packages").agg(
        {"Score": "max", "Street": "last", "Date": "last"}
    )
)
```

Prints:

```
          Score   Street       Date
Packages                           
p1          8.1      Oak 2020-09-29
p2          9.0  Orchard 2021-12-20
p3          7.8     Main 2021-05-04
```

Comment: Using the date format the OP is using (YYYY-MM-DD), there is no need to change the dates to datetime since they're alphanumerically ordered.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `merge` in order to merge the queried `ndf` with the original `df` with `on = ['Packages','Date']` in order to correlate the `Street` with `Date` and `Packages` column without considering for correlation with `Score`

```
ndf = df.groupby(['Packages']).agg({'Score':'max', 'Date':'max'})[['Score','Date']]
ndf = ndf.merge(df, on = ['Packages','Date'], how = 'inner')

# Filter out unnecessary columns
ndf['Score'] = ndf['Score_x'] # Use Score_x column on the left side (ndf) instead of Score_y on the right side (df)
ndf = ndf[['ID', 'Packages', 'Score', 'Date', 'Street']]
print(ndf)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method but keep the same display result as expected:

```
>>> df.sort_values("Date").groupby("Packages", as_index=False) \
      .apply(lambda x: x.loc[[x["Score"].idxmax()]] \
                        .assign(Street=x["Street"].iloc[-1],
                                Date=x["Date"].iloc[-1])) \
      .reset_index(drop=True)

    ID Packages  Score   Street        Date
0   12       p1    8.1      Oak  2020-09-29
1   22       p2    9.0  Orchard  2021-12-20
2  445       p3    7.8     Main  2021-05-04
```

Maybe easier and more understanding:

```
df_score = df.sort_values("Score").groupby("Packages", as_index=False)[["ID", "Packages", "Score"]].last()
df_date = df.sort_values("Date").groupby("Packages", as_index=False)[["Street", "Date"]].last()
```

```
>>> pd.merge(df_score, df_date)
    ID Packages  Score   Street        Date
0   12       p1    8.1      Oak  2020-09-29
1   22       p2    9.0  Orchard  2021-12-20
2  445       p3    7.8     Main  2021-05-04
```